# Multiple slugs in href

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to href to my model instances that take a 'model_slug' and 'category_slug' argument. It's giving me `NoReverseMatch`

**html**

```
{% for model in models %}

                <a class="btn btn-outline" href="{% url 'main:model_detail_view' model.category_slug model.model_slug %}">View Model</a>

{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def model_detail_view(request, category_slug, model_slug):
    model = Model.objects.get(category__category_slug=category_slug, model_slug=model_slug)
    context = {
        "models": model,
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name='main/model_detail.html', context=context)
```

**urls.py**

```
path("products/<str:category_slug>/<str:model_slug>/", views.model_detail_view, name="model_detail_view"),
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `category__category_slug` in your template:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline" href=
"{% url 'main:model_detail_view' model.category.category_slug model.model_slug %}">
View Model</a>
```

Since you are filtering `model` by its fk relation to `category` in your view.

Comment: This should probably be `category.category_slug`, right..?

Comment: @Dabble yeah ty didn't catch that.

Answer (score 2):

The slug of the `category` (the `category_slug`) is stored in an object linked by a `category` foreign key. You thus can access it with:

```
{% url 'main:model_detail_view' model.category.category_slug model.model_slug %}
```

You probably should use `.select_related(..)` here to fetch the related `Category` object in your database query, and avoid a second roundtrip to the database:

```
def model_detail_view(request, category_slug, model_slug):
    model = Model.objects.select_related(
        'category'
    ).get(category__category_slug=category_slug, model_slug=model_slug)
    context = {
        'model': model,
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name='main/model_detail.html', context=context)
```

Note that your `model` is a *single* `Model` object, so you can *not* iterate over it like `{% for model in models %}`. You thus render the template with a variable named `model` without a `{% for … %}` loop in the template.

Comment: Still getting the same error not sure why.. It's showing that it's getting the model_slug fine but category_slug is blank

Comment: @GTA.sprx: your `category` has a non-empty slug (you can check the database).

Comment: I'm not sure what 'non-empty slug' means. I'm assuming it means the value is not equal to `None` ?

Comment: @GTA.sprx: no, to the empty string (although `None` is not a good value either).

Comment: Okay I must be missing something here. Your code makes sense to me but I'm not understanding why it's still giving me that error. I'll try doing some reading.

Comment: I thing I know what's wrong. My model's `category`attribute is a `ManyToManyField` not a `ForeignKey`. As far as I know `select_related` required a foreign key. Is there any way to use ManyToMany? I use it so I can have some products appear in multiple categories